# The sign of the normal force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

The notes state that $N = mg$. However, if I have a $4\,\rm kg$ box on a table, taking upward as positive

$$N = -mg = -4 \cdot (-9.81)$$

Is this correct? If it is correct, why do the notes state that $N = mg$? Should I only use the magnitude of gravity?

Comment: Do you want the symbol $N$ to denote just the magnitude of a force, or the magnitude and direction? As a side note, $g$ is usually taken as positive, though I suppose there can be different conventions.

Comment: Then does the above approach correct? If g is positive, you take upward as negative. And the normal force will become negative?

Comment: It usually depends on notation. I generally take $g$ to be negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign is purely based on convention. Usually it is just written as $ F_{n} = -mg $ which does point up, but only because we take $g$ to be negative already. The fact that it is based on convention should make things easier for you, since you can chose which representation that you're comfortable with. Typically though, if you aren't dealing with vectors in vector notation, you do just want to go with the lengths. Questions that don't present info to that depth don't merit answers to the same depth. That said, your book leaves out the negative sign because it is indeed only dealing with magnitudes. Enjoy!

Comment: I disagree. The issue in the question is not about convention. $n=mg$ is correct because $n-w=n-mg=0$ in this situation, not because the sign of $g$ happens to be chosen by convention.

Answer (score 1):

There are two normal forces acting. There is the downward force the box exerts on the table and the upward force the table exerts on the box. The two forces are equal and opposite, as Newton's third law tells us, so one will be positive and one will be negative. Generally we'd say the upward force is positive and the downward force negative.

For simple situations like this we tend to be careless about the sign and just talk about a force of $mg$, but really we should specify which force we mean and the sign. To be fair it's unlikely anyone would get confused about what we meant. Where the system is not static the sign of the force is important as you have to put it into the equation of motion and using the wrong sign will predict the wrong behaviour. Likewise when many forces are present and you need to take the vector sum of forces.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy if you draw the Free body diagram of the box.  The FBD should show only the EXTERNAL forces.  There are 2 external forces.  First, the force of the earth's gravity ON the box which equals Mg and acts in a downward direction (here g = +ve).  Second the force of the table ON the box which is N acting upwards.

Now you decide on your sign convention...if you decide downwards is positive, then

sum of the forces = Mg - N = 0 --> N = Mg  (note, N is negative as it points up and you choose downwards is positive).

If, however you choose upwards to be positive, then N - Mg = 0 --> N = Mg.  Note, since Mg is acting downwards and you've chosen upwards to be positive, then Mg has a negative sign.

In both cases, N = Mg (where g is a positive number).

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the currently accepted answer. Your note, saying $n=mg$, is correct regardless of convention. This issue has got nothing to do with convention.

The issue you have is that you place the terms randomly on either side of the equal sign. You write...

$$n=-mg$$
...but should have written... 
$$n-mg=0$$

When there are forces acting but the object is standing still, then these forces clearly cancel each other out. In other words, if you **add them all up**, then they must cancel out. They must result in zero force when **added together**.

Newton wrote this as his first law:

$$\sum F=0$$

You must add up all the forces (including signs) before rearranging. The issue in the question is that some rearrangement has happened already, since some terms are on the left side and some in the right side of the equal sign.